# Polygon transaction working just fine on Mumbai but not on Mainnet

Tags: node.js, blockchain, web3js, nft, matic

Hello I'm trying to mint an NFT using Polygon and it works just fine on Mumbai but as soon as i switch over to the mainnet the transaction doesn't go through instead of going through in 5 seconds on mumbai. Even though im using the exact same contract just deployed on the mainnet instead of Mumbai and the code is the same too. All im doing is switching the contract address and rpc url but for some reason it just doesn't work on the Polygon mainnet below is the code im using.

```
// Init contract
        const contractABI = require('../../contract-abi.json');
        const contractAddress = config.mintingContractAddress;
        const contract = await new this.web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
        // Mint NFT
        const nft = contract.methods.mintNFT(user.walletAddress, metadataUploadURL, user.paymentAddress).encodeABI();
        // Get gas pricing
        const priorityFees = await axios.get('https://gasstation-mainnet.matic.network');
        const estBaseGas = await this.web3.eth.estimateGas({
          data: nft,
          to: contractAddress,
        });
        console.log('USING GAS: ' + estBaseGas);
        // Sign NFT minting transaction
        const totalGas = estBaseGas + priorityFees.data.standard;
        console.log('TOTALGAS: ', Math.round(totalGas).toString());
        const transaction = await this.web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
          {
            from: user.walletAddress,
            to: contractAddress,
            nonce: await this.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(user.walletAddress, 'pending'), // Get count of all transactions sent to the contract from this address including pending ones
            data: nft,
            // maxPriorityFee: priorityFees.data.average, Not supported on Polygon MATIC yet
            gas: Math.round(totalGas).toString(),
            gasPrice: await this.web3.eth.getGasPrice(),
          },
          wallet.privateKey,
        );
        this.logger.silly('Finished signing NFT transaction');
        // Send the transaction that we signed
        const mintT = await this.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(transaction.rawTransaction);
        this.logger.silly('Sent transaction');
        console.log(mintT);
```

Also tried this for signing

```
// Get gas pricing
        const priorityFees = await axios.get('https://gasstation-mainnet.matic.network');
        const estBaseGas = await this.web3.eth.estimateGas({
          data: nft,
          to: contractAddress,
        });
        console.log('USING GAS: ' + estBaseGas);
        // Sign NFT minting transaction
        const totalGas = estBaseGas + priorityFees.data.standard;
        console.log('TOTALGAS: ', Math.round(totalGas).toString());
        console.log('P', priorityFees.data.standard);
        const gp = this.web3.utils.toWei(priorityFees.data.standard.toString(), 'Gwei').toString();
        console.log('GP', gp);
        const transaction = await this.web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(
          {
            from: user.walletAddress,
            to: contractAddress,
            nonce: await this.web3.eth.getTransactionCount(user.walletAddress, 'pending'), // Get count of all transactions sent to the contract from this address including pending ones
            data: nft,
            // maxPriorityFee: priorityFees.data.average, Not supported on Polygon MATIC yet
            gas: '1000000',
            gasPrice: gp,
          },
          wallet.privateKey,
        );
```

Mempool explorer for transaction that takes forever and nearly instant one.
Forever:
[image: Taking forever]
Instant:
[image: Fast]
One on mainnet that used 30 gwei of gas:
[image: 30 gwei]
Does anybody know why this is happening?
Also yes i do know that the fast one does have 2 extra gwei in gas but even setting it to that manually it still takes forever and according to https://polygonscan.com/gastracker even with one gwei it should be processed within 30 seconds. Even when using 50 Gwei it seems to take hours to process or maybe it's being dropped? The transactions don't even seem to be getting to the contract they are just stuck somewhere in the chain.
contract address: 0xa915E82285e6F82eD10b0579511F48fD716a2043

contract source code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract MyNFT is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    event MintedNFT(address recipent,string tokenURI,address artist, uint256 tokenID);

    mapping(uint256 => address) private artists; // Used to store token ids => artist addresses
    // mapping(uint256 => uint256) private royalties; // tokenId => royaltyPercentage
    // mapping(uint256 => address) private nftMintInitators; // Used to store token ids => sender addresses
    // mapping(uint256 => bool) private royaltiesSet;

    constructor(string memory name_, string memory symbol_)
        ERC721(name_, symbol_) {
        }

    // // Support for https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981
    // /// @notice Called with the sale price to determine how much royalty
    // //          is owed and to whom.
    // /// @param _tokenId - the NFT asset queried for royalty information
    // /// @param _salePrice - the sale price of the NFT asset specified by _tokenId
    // /// @return receiver - address of who should be sent the royalty payment
    // /// @return royaltyAmount - the royalty payment amount for _salePrice
    // function royaltyInfo(
    //     uint256 _tokenId,
    //     uint256 _salePrice
    // ) external view returns (
    //     address receiver,
    //     uint256 royaltyAmount
    // ) {
    //     return (
    //         artists[_tokenId],
    //         _salePrice * royalties[_tokenId] // Take percentage
    //     );
    // }

    // function updateRoyaltyPercentage(
    //     uint256 royaltyPercentage, // In decimal like 0.5 or 0.25 (Send 0.0 for no royalties)
    //     uint256 tokenID
    // ) public {
    //     if (msg.sender == nftMintInitators[tokenID] && royaltiesSet[tokenID] == false) {
    //         royalties[tokenID] = royaltyPercentage;
    //         royaltiesSet[tokenID] = true;
    //     }
    // }

    function mintNFT(address recipient,
     string memory tokenURI,
     address artist // Address for the artist not using _msgSender() because this transaction is sent by the users NFT holding account
     )
        public
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(recipient, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        artists[newItemId] = artist;
        // nftMintInitators[newItemId] = msg.sender;
        // royaltiesSet[newItemId] = false;

        emit MintedNFT(recipient,tokenURI,artist,newItemId);

        return newItemId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and share the contract source code (incl. the constructor argument values if there are any) or verify it on the [blockchain explorer](https://polygonscan.com/address/0xa915e82285e6f82ed10b0579511f48fd716a2043#code). It's possible that the `mintNFT()` fails on the mainnet because of some dependency call (that might go through on the testnet but fails on the mainnet).

Comment: @PetrHejda ok added

Answer (score 0):

You can test with simple code just to mint one NFT. Adding gasPrice and gasLimit parameters directly into minting function could help

```
 const hre = require("hardhat");
 async function main() {
     const NFT = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("NFTNAME");
     const WALLET_ADDRESS = "0xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0xa915E82285e6F82eD10b0579511F48fD716a2043"
     const contract = NFT.attach(CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
     mintedNFT = await contract.mintNFT(WALLET_ADDRESS,{ gasLimit: 285000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('30', 'gwei')});
     console.log("NFT minted:", mintedNFT);

}
main().then(() => process.exit(0)).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exit(1);
});
```